# Tirar mes e anoSSIS

Tags: ssis, variáveis

Tenho uma variável contendo ela uma expressão que corresponde a um diretorio de pastas.

Eu quero que apareça o ano e o mes anterior:

"c:\" + SUBSTRING( (dt_str, 50, 1252)GETDATE(), 1, 4 ) + "\" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) MONTH( DATEADD("MONTH",-1,GETDATE()) ),2)

Sai:
c:\2017\09

, mas imaginemos que estamos no mês Janeiro e o mês anterior é (12) e o ano também é o anterior. Da forma como está , todos os ano me obrigaria a intervir.

Não existe nenhuma forma de contornar isto e meter uma relação entre o mês e o ano, para que seja sempre de forma automática?

Answer (score 0):

Consegue com um case, o case nas expressions do SSIS é desta maneira: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Olá @Tiago. Evite colocar apenas _links_ na sua resposta. Pegue em trechos de código que possam suportar a sua resposta.

Comment: @JoãoMartins, melhor que trechos de código, só os documentos oficiais da microsoft...